# Destructor of a class implicitly defined

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, explicit-constructor

Consider the case of class which does not have a `destructor` and `constructor` explicitly declared by the developer. I understand that a `destructor` for a class will be `implicitly declared` in this case. Then is it true that the `destructor` is `implicitly defined`, only when an object of the class is about to be destroyed?

Is the behavior of constructor also the same as above. Is it `implicitly defined` only when an object of the class is created?

**EDIT**

```
class A {
  public:

};
int main() {

}
```

In the above code, ~A() will be implicitly declared. My question is whether it true that the definition for the destructor will be made implicitly, only if an object of the class is instantiated like

```
class A {
      public:

    };
    int main() {
      A a;
    }
```

Or is it implicitly defined, even if object instantiation is not done ?

Comment: Maybe we can give better answers if you explain why this is relevant.

Comment: Are you making some sort of distinction between `implicitly declared` and `implicitly defined`? I am really struggling to understand the question...

Comment: I have added some code snippet for clarity.

Comment: @LinuxPenseur: What do you need this for?

Comment: @phresnel : I am studying the basics of the C++ language. I want a concrete idea of what is happening. If ever someone asks me the question after i have mastered the language, i should be able to give the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, implicitly declared default constructors and destructors are implicitly defined when they are used to create or destroy instances of the object. In the words of the standard (C++11):

> 12.1/6: A default constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used
>   (3.2) to create an object of its class type (1.8) or when it is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration.
>
> 12.4/5: A destructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used (3.2) to
>   destroy an object of its class type (3.7) or when it is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration.

So they are defined in your second code snippet, which creates and destroys an object of type `A`, but not in the first, which doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, it is often impossible to decide whether an object is ever created/destroyed in any non-trivial program*, on the other hand, it doesn't really matter as long as the observable behavior remains the same.

However, there is a thin line between `defined when object created/destroyed`, and `defined if needed`. In my example below, `Foo::Foo()` needs to be defined, because there is the potential for it to be needed. However, you ask whether it is defined when the object is created, and the latter is not decidable.

---

*:

```
class Foo {};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc>1) Foo(); // <- impossible to decide if ever constructed/destroyed
}

// On the other hand, compiler might be smart enough to observe that
// Foo does not have any visible behaviour, remove Foo entirely, and in
// effect spit out this:
int main() {}
```

Comment: It's always possible to determine whether a program needs to contain code to create or destroy an object (as your example clearly does); that's what determines whether the implicit constructor or destructor gets defined.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Of course you are right, but the OP basically asks not `is defined if needed?`, but rather `is defined _when_ object is created` (I updated my post in hope to make it more clear).

Answer (score 0):

Whether a function is defined is not something that is determined at runtime, so the destructor cannot be "*defined, only when an object [..] is **about** to be destroyed*" simply because your executable is static and not created for a specific run.

However, if no calls to your destructor exist in the final executable, the linker <s>*might* chose to</s> *will* remove the function altogether.

---

For the last point, consider this example:

```
class A {
  A() {}
  ~A() {}
};
class B {
  A a; // cannot access dtor nor ctor of A
};
```

If you never ever instantiate `B` this will actually compile and link because no `B::B()` and no `B::~B()` ever is synthesised. However, if you try to create an object of `B` the compiler will call you some colourful names, simply because you forced it to synthesise `B::B()` and `B::~B()` which it cannot do.

Comment: If no calls to the destructor exist, then the compiler won't define the destructor at all, because that's what the standard says. And your example doesn't just work by luck; it works because the constructor isn't defined unless `B` is instantiated.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: How does the compiler know? The calls could be made by other compilation units?

Comment: The same way it handles inline functions. The constructor/destructor is defined in every translation unit that needs it, and duplicates are sorted out by the linker if necessary.